Нужно написать код, который выводит количество чисел с нечётным количеством цифр. Но мой код ничего не выводит на экран. Помогите, пожалуйста
default rel

section .data
    nums        db 12, 45, 67, 89
    nums_len    equ $ - nums
    out_msg     db "Number of elements with odd digits: ", 0
    out_len     dq ($ - out_msg)  ; Правильно сохраняем длину строки out_msg
    formatStr   db "%d", 10, 0    ; Форматная строка для wsprintf с новой строкой

section .bss
    handle      resq 1
    count       resd 1
    buffer      resb 64

section .text
    extern GetStdHandle
    extern WriteConsoleA
    extern wsprintfA
    extern ExitProcess

    global main

main:
    sub     rsp, 40                  ; Выделение места для shadow space

    ; Получение дескриптора стандартного устройства вывода
    mov     ecx, -11                 ; STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call    GetStdHandle
    mov     [handle], rax

    ; Подсчет чисел с нечетным количеством цифр
    lea     rsi, [nums]
    mov     ecx, nums_len
    xor     edi, edi

count_loop:
    movzx   rax, byte [rsi]
    test    rax, rax
    jz      next_number              ; Пропуск, если число нулевое
    mov     ebx, 10
    xor     rdx, rdx

count_digits:
    div     rbx
    inc     rdx                      ; Инкремент счетчика цифр
    test    rax, rax
    jnz     count_digits

    test    rdx, 1
    jnz     increment_count
    jmp     short next_number

increment_count:
    inc     edi

next_number:
    inc     rsi
    loop    count_loop

    ; Форматирование и вывод количества
    mov     [count], edi
    lea     rcx, [buffer]
    mov     rdx, formatStr
    mov     r8d, [count]
    call    wsprintfA

    ; Вывод сообщения
    mov     rcx, [handle]
    lea     rdx, [out_msg]
    mov     r8, qword [out_len]      ; Исправленный доступ к длине строки
    lea     r9, [rsp+28]
    call    WriteConsoleA

    ; Вывод числа
    lea     rdx, [buffer]
    mov     r8, qword 64             ; Максимальный размер буфера
    lea     r9, [rsp+28]
    call    WriteConsoleA

    add     rsp, 40                  ; Возврат выделенного места
    xor     ecx, ecx                 ; Код выхода 0
    call    ExitProcess


Программа составлена не по правилам Windows API. x64 calling convention почитайте.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
